# Wizard to create stock.picking from another model - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this code for the wizard:

```
class generate_stock_picking(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'generate.stock.picking'

isbns = fields.One2many('order.lines', 'order_id', 'ISBN')
production_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.print.order', 'Print Order')
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', 'Company',default='_default_company')
location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string="Source Location")
location_dest_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string="Destination Location")

@api.model
def default_get(self, fields):
    res = super(generate_stock_picking, self).default_get(fields)
    isbns = []
    if self.env.context.has_key('active_id'):
        production_order = self.env.context['active_id']
        order = self.env['bsi.print.order'].browse(production_order)
        sp_types = self.env['stock.picking.type'].search([
        ('code', '=', 'incoming')
        ])
        if len(sp_types) > 0:
            for line in order.order_lines:
                if line.remaining_qty > 0:
                    val = {
                        #'origin': line.name,
                        'isbn':line.isbn.id,
                        'qty': line.remaining_qty,
                        'picking_type_id': sp_types[0].id,
                        }
                    isbns.append([0,0,val])
            res.update({'isbns':isbns,'production_order':production_order})
        return res

@api.multi    
def generate(self):
    if self.isbns:
        order_lines = []
        sp_types = self.env['stock.picking.type'].search([
        ('code', '=', 'incoming')
        ])
        print_order = self.env['stock.picking'].create({
            'origin': self.name.id,
            'state': 'draft',
            'stock_picking_lines': self.production_order.id,
            'picking_type_id': sp_types[0].id,
            })
        for line in self.isbns:
            order_lines.append(self.env['bsi.print.order.lines'].create({
                'print_order':print_order.id,
                'isbn':line.isbn.id,
                'qty':line.qty}))
            prod_isbn = self.env['bsi.print.order.lines'].search([('production_order','=',self.production_order.id),
                                                           ('isbn','=',line.isbn.id)])
            prod_isbn.consumed_qty = line.qty
        print_order.write({'order_lines':[(6,0,map(lambda x:x.id,order_lines))]})
        tree_view_id = self.env.ref('stock.vpicktree').id
        form_view_id = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form').id
        self.production_order.state = 'delivered'
        return {
            'name': _('Stock Picking'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'stock.picking',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'views': [(tree_view_id, 'tree'),(form_view_id, 'form')],
            'view_id':tree_view_id,
            'res_id': [print_order.id],
            'domain': [('id', 'in', [print_order.id])]
             }
```

This should create a `stock.picking` from `bsi.print.order`

But it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\wizard\generate_stock_picking.py", line 45, in generate
AttributeError: 'generate.stock.picking' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I need to pass the `name` and few other fields, since `stock.picking` has One2many to `stock.move`.

This wizard was originally conceived to just pass lines from one model to another.

On this case it should pass lines as `stock.move` and few other fields outside lines to `stock.picking`.

I have this method which does something similar (and it actually works) but it's not a wizard:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['stock.picking'] 
    for record in self:
        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'name': 'name',
                'product_id': rec.isbn.id,
                'product_uom': rec.isbn.uom_id.id,
                'date_expected': time.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT),
                'product_uom_qty': rec.qty,
                'location_id': record.location_id.id,
                'location_dest_id': record.location_dest_id.id,
                }
            ))
        sp_types = self.env['stock.picking.type'].search([
        ('code', '=', 'incoming')
        ])
        if len(sp_types) > 0:
            copy_record.create({
                'origin': record.name,
                'picking_type_id': sp_types[0].id,
                'move_lines': order_lines, 
                'move_type': 'direct',
                'priority': '1',
                'company_id': record.company_id.id,
            })
    self.write({'state': 'delivered',},)
```

The lines I know already how to pass them, but how do I adapt the `stock.picking` fields? (ie: copy_record on create_printy method)

Comment: Error is coming from method: `def generate(self)` in that at the time of creation record of stock.picking you try to insert name in  keyname 'origin' value is 'self.name.id' but your self model means current model does not contain any field  'name' so might be this error is coming from this. Field is not there in current model and you try to pass value of that field to another model so might this issue is there.

Comment: But 'name' is necessary on the other model, hmmm, going to check that

Comment: If 'name' is necessary then just create that kind of field in active model and after that pass value to another model.